# Отправка email woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

При заказе email не отправляется на почту(покупателя) gmail и яндекс, но при этом спокойно отправляется на mailforspam. Где нужно искать причину?

Comment: Причину искать в настройках отправки почты. Не отправляются письма или попадают под фильтр или в спам? Попробуйте использовать smtp отправку почты.

Answer (score 0):

В современном мире все письма надо отправлять через проверенные SMTP-сервера, например, smtp.yandex.ru, smtp.google.com. Так как хостинг-провайдеры могут заблокировать РНР функцию `mail()`, например, причин такому масса или ваши письма тупо падают в спам за неверную настройку. Для использования этих SMTP от yandex или google достаточно завести себе почтовый ящик у соответствующего провайдера.

Чтобы настроить все это добро в WordPress, рекомендую плагин [WP Mail SMTP](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

Answer (score 0):

Не "не отправляются", а "не получают" (раз уж на др сервера доставляется). Или скорее всего валиться в спам.

Для анализа почты можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь плагином https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=email+log

Для того, чтобы письма не попадали в спам стоит настроить SPF и DKIM на сервере.