# Не получаю письмо, на указанную почту в Contact Form 7

Tags: html, wordpress, form, forms, contact-form7

Проблема заключается в том, что плагин Contact Form 7 на WP не отправляет письма, ибо они не доходят до указанного адресата.

У меня есть хостинг на fornex, с бесплатным выделенным доменом - http://m117919.hostru08.fornex.host и под него есть почта - ****@m117919.hostru08.fornex.host.

Я настроил Contact From 7: Указал поле кому - мой собственный имейл, указал от кого - указал ту новую почту от fornex ****@m117919.hostru08.fornex.host, что является допустимым если учитывать название домена и хостинга, ну и заполнил другие поля как заголовок, содержимое итп, что является индивидуальным решением, в конце концов консоль ошибок не выдала и форма на странице нориально высветилась.

Но при отправке формы, сообщение не приходит на мой собственный имейл, который указал в поле - "Кому".

Раньше, когда делал предыдущий сайт, все работало, тут же выполнены те же самые действия, но увы... не отправляет сообщения от той почты домена, ибо оно не приходит на мою почту.

Конфигурация плагина Contact Form 7: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMJLp.jpg

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570478/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-email-woocommerce/614260#614260